# Load default action and controller if none were found

Tags: kohana, kohana-3

I'm not sure if it's possible, but what i need is to load default `controller` and `action` if specified `controller` has not been found from the `url`, so let's say if i have this url:

`http://mywebsite.com/john`

It would have to call `user` controller and `selected_user` action,

And if i have url `http://mywebsite.com/pages/profile`

it would have to call `pages` controller and `profile` action because both has been specified and found

Is there a way to do it?

I am using `Kohana 3.2`

**EDIT** Here is my htaccess:

```
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Installation directory
RewriteBase /ep/

# Protect hidden files from being viewed
<Files .*>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny From All
</Files>

# Protect application and system files from being viewed
RewriteRule ^(?:application|modules|system)\b.* index.php/$0 [L]

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]
```

`/ep` is my directory in `htdocs` also i did set `'base_url'   => '/ep/',` in my `bootstrap` as well

Comment: What web server are you using? apache? IIS?

Comment: @AlexP Right now im using apache, but im not sure yet what will my clients use

Comment: Have you already configured Apache to rewrite the URL?Or are you just  trying to work out how to set the default controller/action?

Comment: @AlexP Well i didn't do anything with apace, but did set up bootstrap and .htaccess with default settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming mod_rewriting is enabled and the .htaccess file is configured correctly. All you need to do is specify a new route within the bootstrap, after the current default one.

For example:

```
<?php

  Route::set('default', '(<controller>(/<action>(/<stuff>)))', array('stuff' => '.*'))
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'welcome',
        'action' => 'index',
  ));

  /** Set a new route for the users **/
  Route::set(
    "users", "<name>", array("name" => ".*")
  )->defaults(array(
    'controller' => 'users',
    'action' => 'selected_user'
  ));

  /** Within the selected_user method you can then check the request for the "name" 
    validate the user parameter (parhaps against the db) and then again route the correct
    pages/profile if found

    e.g.
  **/

  $username = $this->request->param('name');
  if ($username == "alexp") {
    /** reroute to the users/profile controller with data **/
  }

?>
```

Edit: also I forgot to mention that the above routes will be called for anything after the base Uri so "http://mysite.com/john" and "http://mysite.com/89s88" will also try to use that route. You could imagine allot of routes being needed over time, so best at least stick to a minimum of /controller/action varieties or you may other wise find yourself with some complicated regex in the routes where it is unneeded.

Comment: I still get  `[404 ]: The requested URL testas was not found on this server.` also i have updated my question with .htaccess contents